# Hiding Elements with JQuery using a select box

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the tr with the ID of articleNnumber to hide itself until Update or Clarification is selected from the select with the ID of type. I have tried several different jquery examples I have found here but I for the life of me can not get it to work and decided to ask for help

```
  <form id="test">
            <table id="article">
                <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Frist and Lastname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Account:</th>
                <td><select name="client">
                        <option value="">Select an Account:</option>
                        <option value="test1">test 1</option>
                        <option value-"test2">test</option>
                    </select>
               </td>
               <tr>
               <th>Type:</th>
               <td><select id="type">
                        <option value="">Select One...</option>
                        <option value="new">New</option>
                        <option value="update">Update</option>
                        <option value="clarify">Clarification</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <tr id="articleNumber">>
                    <th>Article Number:</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="article" placeholder="Enter Article" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>

    </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post some of the example code you thought would help you achieve this?

Comment: You have some invalid html (just by a glance - a `tr` is not closed for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to also hide this element if the user toggles away from "Update" or "Clarification"

Start by making `articleNumber` hidden

```
<tr id="articleNumber" hidden>
```

The add the following JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#type').change(function() {       
        if($(this).val() === 'update' || $(this).val() === 'clarification') {
            $('#articleNumber').show();
        } else {
            $('#articleNumber').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/n4zrquj9/)

Comment: Thank you sir I do not knowg much about jquery or javascript that helps. I understand the code but would have had a hard time writing it from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, hide article row by default and use following js code

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   if($(this).val()!='new'){
       $("#articleNumber").show();
   }else{
       $("#articleNumber").hide();
   }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s93zvgju/)

Comment: this does not consider if the `<select>` contains other items. OP specified show if "Update " or "Clarification "